# PyCharm error:is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pycharm

I am using Python version:
  **Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
  (AMD64)] on win32**

So i tried installing **numpy-1.13.0rc2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl** since it is a 3.5 version and 64 bit.

But it shows the error: **numpy-1.13.0rc2+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

Before using Python 3.5 I was using Python 3.6 and it has no problem installing numpy+mkl and scipy but it has problem installing sklearn due to its compatible problem.

So now I'm using 3.5 in order to make it compatible to sklearn but it has error installing numpy+mkl and scipy instead!

matplotlib, pandas and numpy is installed smoothly without errors though.

The files were downloaded from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: maybe a x86/amd64 confusion? make sure you run everything including pycharm as  amd64

Comment: The pip version is the latest already(9.0.01)